# Application Design Reminders (UILocalNotifications?)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikit

A quick question on application design. I was wonder if any of you know roughly how the notification/reminder system in the application "Day One" works?

Basically I think it uses UILocalNotifications, it has a feature which helps remind users to use the app, by setting a reminder with a given frequency.

I am wondering how this was implemented?

I don't think it can be that"Day One" sets a constant reocurring UILocalnotication - as surely if the app was deleted this would continue to bug users and cause issues?

Maybe they use push notificaitons?

Comment: `UILocalNotification` will/should be removed by iOS if the user delete the app which scheduled them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it is using `UILocalNotification` with recurrency. You can set notification to "popup" every day in the same time for example. Like this:

```
notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't think it can be that"Day One" sets a constant reocurring UILocalnotication - as surely if the app was deleted this would continue to bug users and cause issues?`

`UILocalNotification` exists only if the app exists. If the app is deleted system will remove all the scheduled notification of that app. It is not going to annoying users or cause any issues after removing the app.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read and answer, I gave correct to djserva, as he answered first.